# How to get higher quality for second camera in stereoscopy multi-view?

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm new here but I use your platform to solve some problems that I sometimes have with blender.

So I use stereoscopy multi-view a lot for creating different views of the same object. But somehow since a few weeks the first camera in the list renders correctly but the second and all the other camera's after that render in low quality. See the images.

I'm using Eevee to render. My sampling rate is 100 for Render and Viewport. It doesn't change the output of the second camera.
For shadows I have:
Cube size: 512 px
Cascade size: 1024 px
Soft shadows is checked.

I hope you can help?

[image: Low quality second camera]

[image: Normal quality]

Solution:
I upgraded to 3.2.2 and Blender renders the images in a correct way.

Comment: I did a test on my mac and there it seems to be working in a correct way. The same file. Is it some settings in Blender? Or not enough memory? I have 64GB internal memory and my graphics card is a 3060Ti.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.2.2 and Blender renders the images in a correct way.